# what is the correct method to fill select use jQuery and laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a form for adding Salaries, in this form there is select Fonction_id foreign key from table function in table Salaries (belongsTo relation between them), I want to fill this select, knowing that I use laravel and jquery, what is the good method to do.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
     <select class="form-control" name="fonction_id">
          <option></option>
          <option> fonction_id </option>
      </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "good method"? Why not simply add all values to the markup?

Comment: @NicoHaase Suppose you are in my position what way you will work to fill this select ??

Comment: I'd edit the template and use a loop to fill that select. I see no need for jQuery at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It do not need to jquery.Do it as bellow:

First select your objects from database in controller and pass it from controller to view by `compact` like this:

```
$models = Yourmodel::All();
return view('yourview',compact('models');
```

And in your view render it in foreach as this:

```
  <select>
      @foreach($models as $model)
        <option>{{$model->yourfield}}</option>@endforeach </select>
```